# Why come some docx-files are transformed to swf and not others

Tags: alfresco

We are using Alfresco Transformation Server for our transformations. I have two problematic documents that are not converted properly when previewed in document-details in Alfresco Share.

When looking into the ATS-history view I can see that the conversion that is requested is from docx -> swf instead of from docx -> pdf which I had expected.

The preview is requested from Google Chrome and we are running Alfresco 4.2.6.

The mimetype of the document is "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" (which all other docx-documents that is converted to pdf also if of)

Comment: Are you sure the document is really of the right type? If you download the document, and run `file` or use the Apache Tika App in `--detect` mode, does it report the document as being actually some other type (eg a `.doc` accidentally renamed to `.docx`)?

Comment: The file command reports: Microsoft OOXML and MimetypeService.guessMimetype in java says its the one above mentioned in the question. So yeah it seems to be of correct type.